# How to validate a query without executing in PowerBuilder

Tags: validation, syntax, powerbuilder

wondering if there is way to validate a query before executing

Is there way to check/validate Query without executing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that we validate SQL is to add a condition to the SQL that could never be true.

Example:

```
long ll_rc
long ll_result
string ls_sql, ls_test
string ls_message

//Arbitrary SQL
ls_sql = "SELECT * FROM DUAL"

//This SQL when executed will always return 0 if successful.
ls_test = "select count(*) from ( " + ls_sql + " WHERE 1 = 2 )" 

DECLARE l_cursor DYNAMIC CURSOR FOR SQLSA ;
PREPARE SQLSA FROM :ls_test;
OPEN DYNAMIC l_cursor;

ll_rc = SQLCA.SQLCODE
choose case ll_rc
    case 0
        //Success
        ls_message = "SQL is properly formed"
    case 100
        //Fetched row not found. This should not be the case since we only opened the cursor
        ls_message = SQLCA.SQLERRTEXT
    case -1
        //Error; the statement failed. Use SQLErrText or SQLDBCode to obtain the detail.
        ls_message = SQLCA.SQLERRTEXT
end choose

CLOSE l_cursor ; //This will fail if open cursor failed. 

messagebox( "Result", ls_message )
```

Note: If your SQL is VERY complicated, which I suspect it isn't, the database optimizer may take several seconds to prepare your SQL. It will be significantly less time than if you run the entire query.

Comment: That seems workable solution. The easy way i think is that i search the WHERE and right after WHERE i add the where clause " 1= 2 AND " . That should work. Yes, queries are expected to be very complicated but i am making just the interface to store diagnostic queries and their fixes in DB. Just to give error message if syntax is not correct. Thanks a lot. I had the same idea in mind but i was in the impression that i will get something i did not read from PB help before.

Answer (score 0):

Since the database is the final arbitrator for what is "valid" (table and column names and such) the general answer is no.  Now you could come up with a class in PB which checks statement syntax, object names, etc. so you wouldn't have to touch the db but it would be obsolete as soon as any changes were made to the db.

Comment: i am sorry, i got no clue what that means. Please help me with more detail.

Comment: Not sure what you are after.  Do you want to interact with the DB at all in checking your queries?  If you do then Eric's solution seems fine.  If you don't you are going to have to create your own SQL parser based on the rules/syntax of the DB you are using and  'manually' check your statements.

Comment: I wanted just the verification of queries before i execute them. So DB interaction is must. Yes, i believe Eric's solution will work in most cases. Thanks a lot for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Put the select statement in any script and compile it.  Part of the work will be to check the SQL syntax against the database you are connected to.
Watch out: you need at least one bound variable in the column list of your SQL statement. This is not the case for other DML statements.

Example:
in my case:

```
select noms into :ls_ttt  from contacts;
```

results in a message `Unknown columns 'noms' in 'field list'`.

However,

```
select nom into :ls_ttt  from contacts;
```

does not show any error.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My diagnostics_table has two columns one for query_to_check_issues and second is for query_to_fix_issue. i have to check syntax of both queries  before i set any status or save  queries back to DB. In this case there  is no need to put INTO in those queries.

Comment: So, you mean to do that programmatically.  I did not understand that point.  In such a case, the answer of Eric Glenn is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Marc, i will try my best to avoid such confusion from now on, that happened because of just two lines of my question.